# SSL converted web system can not work with third pirty Payment service

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

My Web app works with a Payment service called [Stripe](https://stripe.com/).
Stripe proceeds the payment by [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

I do have a Stripe webhook that is successfully caught and processed in Stripe's TEST MODE, on http local host server.
http://3.129.28.206/subscriptions/webhook/

When switching to Stripe's LIVE MODE DATA, I need to SSL converted "http" to "https"
So I set a Load Balancer and exposed the server over HTTPS by AWS.

However, the webhook returns error saying Timed out connecting to remote host,
https://customsrulingsdb.com/subscriptions/webhook/

When the URL is SSL converted from "http" to "https", is there anything I need to fix working with
third pirty to proceed payment?

I used below two tools but I can not figure out what the problem is.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

https://dns.google.com/query?name=&rr_type=ALL&ecs=

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your firewall/security group.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Thank you for your answer. I'm using AWS to set SSL.
So I read this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html
But I can not figure out what's wrong because I did not set up anything about the firewall and I can access my website from my desktop PC, Laptop PC, and smartphone. You can not see my website content?

Comment: @Michael Hampton I brought my smartphone outside and access the page, then I found out that I can not see the page. It must be my setting problem. I'll try again and may ask a further detailed question in another post. Thank you very much.